# Service Worker Loading Synchronously

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, workbox, angular-service-worker

I'm building a website implementing service workers for the first time. I was testing the performance and I was getting around 500ms. I tried running the performance test in a private window and it took about double. When I looked at the page load, it looks like the service worker is loading not only first, but synchronously, and it lasts around 500ms by itself. Note that the one that is taking so long isn't my js file, but the workbox library, which I'm loading this way: `importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');` Could someone give me some insight on this. Is it really loading synchronously? Is there any other way to solve this? Does this only loads the first time? Thank you in advance.

Here are some screenshots:

Regular Load

[image: Regular Load]

Private Window Load

[image: Private Window Load]

Comment: Do you have a public example of this to look at? It sounds pretty odd.

Comment: @abraham not currently. This is going to be in production in a very short time. I guess I could add the link then.